# Use of max and min "functions"

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

"Let a,x,y be elements of R. If a < min(x,y) then a < x and a < y"

The above is a theorem that I encountered in my Real Analysis course. I do not want to ask about what it means, but rather concerning the **"min(x,y)"** being used. **The nature of it I am not clear about**, even after a conversation with my lecturer about it. This is within the context of **proving limits for the reals**.

My **current** understanding: this allows us to ensure that we have a positive real number, that min(x,y) is assuredly so.

I have also seem a **similar** thing in the context of epsilon-N proofs (sequences) , but min is replaced with max.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Perhaps if you gave an example of a use of $\min$ where you're not clear why it's being used.

Comment: I think the OP refers to the unfortunate case in which it is necessary to use a "min" to define a $\delta$ to prove a limit. If so it is a good question, I've had many students asking this during office hours..

Answer (score 3):

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. If $x<y$, then $\min \{x,y\} := x$; if $x > y$, then $\min \{x,y \} := y$; if $x = y$, then $\min \{x,y\} := x = y$.

So $\min$ eats a pair of real numbers and vomits the smaller one. I think you can now sense how $\max$ is similarly defined.

Comment: Yep, I can see how the max works. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing obscure here.   The minimum, $\min(x,y)$, is the least of the real values, $x$ and $y$.   Just that.

$$\min(x,y) \mathop{:=}\begin{cases} x & : x< y \\[1ex] y & : x\geq y\end{cases}$$

Likewise the maximum value:

$$\max(x,y) \mathop{:=}\begin{cases} x & : x> y \\[1ex] y & : x\leq y\end{cases}$$

So when we say, $\forall (x,y,c)\in\Bbb R^3:(c < \min(x, y) \to (c<x)\wedge(c<y))$ we assert that for all real values $x,y,c$ it is that, if $c$ is less than the minimum of $x$ and $y$, then $c$ is less than both $x$ and $y$.

It's a fairly trivial statement, although quite useful to remember.

That is all.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer and explaining its application...I can definitely see what you mean about it being trivial.

Comment: This :={ conditional equals notation is very neat! First I've seen of it, do you know what it's called so I can read up more on it?

Comment: For future readers it's a [conditional] piecewise function https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/piecewise.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop