# Establishing equivalence between an indicator function and a maximum function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that $$\mathbf{1}_{A \cup B} = \text{max}\{\mathbf{1}_A,\mathbf{1}_B\}$$ on my own, mathematically (or to say, that I wish to prove that equation not by explaining with words), but I am not sure how to proceed.  So far, I have this written on my pad: $$\begin{align} \mathbf{1}_{A \cup B} & = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $\omega \in A \cup B$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \\ & = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $\omega \in A$ or $\omega \in B$} \\ 0 & \text{if $\omega \notin A$ and $\omega \notin B$} \end{cases} \end{align}$$ and I have these definitions in mind:
$$\mathbf{1}_{A} := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $\omega \in A$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$ [from $\mathsf{Probability}$, by Karr (1993)] $$\text{max}\{x,y\} := \begin{cases} x & \text{if $x > y$} \\ y & \text{if $x \le y$} \end{cases}$$ [from [$\mathsf{Use \ of \ max \ and \ min 
 \ "functions"}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1437526), reply by Graham Kemp ]

How do you suggest that I should proceed from there?  Perhaps, do you know other ways to define a $\text{max}$ function that may allow me to prove the equation easier?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Prove the equation first for x in A.  Then for x in B and finally when x is in neither.   As the  equation holds for all x in the domain of the functions, it holds for the functions.

Comment: For your case, you are trying to find the $\max(a,b)$, where $a,b \in \{0,1\}$. All you need is to use the fact that $\max(a,b)=0$ if $a=b=0$, and $\max(a,b)=1$ otherwise.

Comment: @WilliamElliot || Do I also include the case when both $x \in A$ and $x \in B$?

Comment: @MathLover || I'm considering your suggestion, but I do think I might be doing it wrong...

\begin{align}
\mathbf{1}_{A \cup B} & = \ldots \\ & = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $\mathbf{1}_{A} = 1$ or $\mathbf{1}_{B} = 1$} \\ 0 & \text{if $\mathbf{1}_{A} = 0$ and $\mathbf{1}_{B} = 0$} \end{cases} \\ & = \begin{cases} \text{max}\{\mathbf{1}_{A},\mathbf{1}_{B}\} = 1 & \text{if $\mathbf{1}_{A} = 1$ or $\mathbf{1}_{B} = 1$} \\
\text{max}\{\mathbf{1}_{A},\mathbf{1}_{B}\} = 0 & \text{if $\mathbf{1}_{A} = 0$ and $\mathbf{1}_{B} = 0$} \end{cases}
\end{align}

Comment: @RalphAnthonyEspos.  Is A or B or (not A & not B) a tautology?

Comment: Both are, though I still feel like including those into the proof.  Too trivial to be stated in the proof?